# count of dynamically created DIVs returning zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Following is my code and relevant HTML , what i wanna do is that i wanna count the number of `search-img-box` within `search-img-ctrl` but i get `0` as output, just to tell here that 
following div `search-img-box` is dynamically created.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var numberOfDivs = jQuery('#search-img-ctrl').filter('.search-img-box').length;
        alert(numberOfDivs);

    });
```

following is my HTML

```
<div id="search-img-ctrl" class="search-img-ctrl">
<div id="search-img-box" class="search-img-box" name="search-img-box">
<img width="335" height="206" src="" alt="">
<ul>
</div>
<div id="search-img-box" class="search-img-box" name="search-img-box">
</div> </div>
```

Comment: Ids should be unique in html. You've got `search-img-box` twice.

Comment: @RobH: let me change it to name may be that make sense, or to class

Comment: I think you want to use `.find()` instead of `.filter()` as `.filter()` would mean you want all `#search-img-ctrl` that are also `.search-img-box`.

Comment: @DominikSchreiber: When i use find i get 1 as output.

Comment: 0 seems to be the correct answer.  You're trying to filter on divs with an id of search-img-ctrl that have the class search-img-box.  I don't see any such divs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t5jcT/

I changed filter to find and got rid of the duplicate ids in the html.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var numberOfDivs = jQuery('#search-img-ctrl').find('.search-img-box').length;
    alert(numberOfDivs);
});
```

or you can use selectors instead of the find as others have pointed out:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var numberOfDivs = jQuery('#search-img-ctrl .search-img-box').length;
    alert(numberOfDivs);
});
```

Comment: Actually, you can get rid of the `Find` by using this selector: `jQuery('#search-img-ctrl .search-img-box').length`

Comment: @CAbbott:exactly there was 1st answer which was fulfilling the requirement but it was then removed so i guess i have to accept this as answer.

Comment: I've modified the answer to contain both.

Comment: @CAbbott if you use the find it will increase the speed of the selector rather than doing it like you have suggested.  [Have a read of this](http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/)

Answer (score 1):

use `.find` instead of `.filter`:

```
var numberOfDivs = jQuery('#search-img-ctrl').find('.search-img-box').length;
alert(numberOfDivs);
```

If you want to only find the number of direct children with that class you can use `.children`

```
var numberOfDivs = jQuery('#search-img-ctrl').children('.search-img-box').length;
```

Also make sure you edit your html so that your html elements don't have duplicate IDs